# why it don't work when I click back arrow icon?

Tags: android

I set the following code in my activity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Why it can't work, when i click back arrow icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement it by yourself：

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```